# Running multiples query on Hbase shell without calling hbase shell again

Tags: shell, awk, hbase

To invoke shell again takes time , i want to execute multiple commands by invoking hbase shell once.Below code run only single query.

```
cmd="echo \"put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1'\"| hbase shell"
```

I want to run multiple queries on single hbase shell call.

```
put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1'
put 'test', 'row2', 'cf:b', 'value2'
put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value3'
```

how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 4 options I know of

**Option 1: semicolons**

```
echo "put 'test','row1','cf:a','value1'; put 'test','row2','cf:b','value2'; put 'test','row3','cf:c','value3'" | hbase shell -n
```

**Option 2: newlines**

```
echo -e "put 'test','row1','cf:a','value1'\nput 'test','row2','cf:b','value2'\nput 'test','row3','cf:c','value3'" | hbase shell -n
```

**Option 3: exec**

```
exec hbase shell -n << EOF
put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1'
put 'test', 'row2', 'cf:b', 'value2'
put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value3'
EOF
```

**Option 4: external file**

```
echo "put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'value1'" > tmpFile
echo "put 'test', 'row2', 'cf:b', 'value2'" >> tmpFile
echo "put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value3'" >> tmpFile
hbase shell -n tmpFile
# obviously this also works: cat tmpFile | hbase shell -n
rm tmpFile
```

Whether to include the `-n` argument is up to you and your use case.  It instructs the shell to stop executing after the first failed command and exit with a non-zero exit code.  It was added with [HBASE-11658](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11658).

I personally prefer option 3 since it's readable and without the need for a temp file.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `-e` for `echo`:

```
echo -e "put ...\n put ...\n"
```

Comment: where I can find information about `-e` option. It works fine, but there is nothing about it in man page.

Comment: Don't know about your manpage, but mine has it.  So does [die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo).  It "enable[s] interpretation of backslash escapes".