# Using HBase put command in airflow bashOperator

Tags: python, bash, airflow, hbase

I'm trying to insert some data into a Hbase table with a Airflow `BashOperator` task. I try to first call the hbase shell and then insert some data into my table:

```
logg_data_to_hbase = BashOperator(
    task_id='data_to_hbase',
    dag=test_dag,
    bash_command="hbase shell && put 'tablename', 'rowname','columnvalue', 1000")
```

I get an error saying ERROR - Bash command failed.

> [2022-01-06 11:01:17,077] {bash_operator.py:100} INFO - Temporary
> script location: /tmp/airflowtmpcKRT8C/data_to_hbaseY7y25j
>
> [2022-01-06 11:01:17,077] {bash_operator.py:110} INFO - Running
> command: hbase shell && put 'tablename', 'rowname','columnvalue', 1000
>
> [2022-01-06 11:01:17,091] {bash_operator.py:119} INFO - Output:
>
> [2022-01-06 11:01:28,659] {bash_operator.py:123} INFO -
> /tmp/airflowtmpcKRT8C/data_to_hbaseY7y25j: line 1: put: command not
> found
>
> [2022-01-06 11:01:28,660] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - Command exited
> with return code 127
>
> [2022-01-06 11:01:28,672] {models.py:1788} ERROR - Bash command failed
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/python-2.7.16-AF-1.10.2-XXX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py",
> line 1652, in _run_raw_task
> result = task_copy.execute(context=context)   File "/opt/python-2.7.16-AF-1.10.2-XXX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py",
> line 131, in execute
> raise AirflowException("Bash command failed") AirflowException: Bash command failed

What do I need to change in order to execute the put-command?

Comment: Try `bash_command = "echo \"put 'tablename', 'rowname','columnvalue', '1000'\" |hbase shell"`

Comment: thanks @SyedShahzer it works like a charm. Please put this as an answer so I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line needs to be changed.

```py
bash_command = "echo \"put 'tablename', 'rowname','columnvalue', '1000'\" | hbase shell"
```

This way the `put` command gets executed in `hbase shell` with the help of `|`.

Comment: how does the syntax look like if we want to insert like two values? Writing `bash_command = "echo \"put 'tablename', 'rowname','columnvalue', '1000 put 'tablename', 'rowname','columnvalue2', '2000''\" | hbase shell"` does not seems to work

Comment: separate the two `put` commands with a semicolon. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667616/running-multiples-query-on-hbase-shell-without-calling-hbase-shell-again)